# OAUTH2 token_key endpoint, security of key exchange

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, openid-provider

As far as I understand the public key to verify e.g. accesstokens is not known to a client, but is taken from the OAUth Endpoint token_key.

Doesn't that mean that the security of my system relies completely on a "key exchange" over a possibly much less secure channel than the token cryptography? E.g. my tokens use 4096 Bit keys, but the SSL Certificate that ensures I'm talking to the correct Endpoint only uses 2048 or my system is configured to accept outdated TLS versions, or I am able somehow (in the corporate network) to create trusted SSL certificates or or or

Why isn't there a more elaborated key exchange mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a place where you can't trust HTTPS, you you have a much bigger issue, but you are correct that OAuth2 is not designed to be secure when HTTPS is untrusted.

The assumption is that HTTPS is trusted.

Comment: So I'm correct that using 4096 Bit Keys for Tokens gives me a false feeling of security, if my SSL only uses 2048 Bit? I think that is a big issue that should not be underestimated. How many hacks doesn't even bother to attack "rhe real thing" because it is much easier to attack at a completely different point, nobody thought about? Thats exactly how 90% of all hacks of presumbly ultra secure things work, I think.

Comment: There's no known direct attacks on this, and computers will not be fast enough to crack a 2048 bit RSA key. You have a false sense of insecurity by thinking you need 4096 keys in this decade probably.